# How to show values from a sql_variant column with LINQ TO SQL (ASP.NET)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, sql-variant

I generate my classes with Linq to Sql, and i have a column "`DataValue`" which is a `sql_variant`.

**MODEL**

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ColumnAttribute(Storage="_DataValue", DbType="Variant", UpdateCheck=UpdateCheck.Never)]
        public object DataValue
        {
            get
            {
                return this._DataValue;
            }
```

**CONTROLLER :**

```
public ActionResult getDataForAPlc()
        {
            int plc = 1; 
            var dataContext = new PLCDataContext();
            var datas = from tag in dataContext.PLC_Data_5m
                            where tag.TagID == plc && tag.TimeStampLocal >= new DateTime(2016, 7, 20) && tag.TimeStampLocal < new DateTime(2016,7,21)
                           orderby tag.TimeStampLocal descending
                           select tag;
            return View(datas);
        }
```

And i used the View `GENERATOR` (Razor) To generate my LIST of Value from my QUERY.

**Problem :** I see all values, except Datavalue. There is nothing, and when i generate the view, By default, DataValue does not appear. I added it on my View.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<DataReports.Models.PLC_Data_5m>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "getDataForAPlc";
}

<h2>getDataForAPlc</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TimeStampLocal)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataTimeStamp)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataQuality)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.DataValue)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeStampLocal)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataTimeStamp)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataQuality)
        </td>
        <td>
           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DataValue)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

And there is no values. Can someone help me? I know that's an object property due to `sql_variant`, but, how to get a value from this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You´ll have to implement a workaround in order to read sql_variant types, as described in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/137509/Reading-sql-variant-in-Entity-Framework